# Google Maps V3 Multiple markers onclick then add info window to marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I currently have a poly which is created onclick and where clicked a marker is dropped and a line is created from the last marker. each marker has another map inside the infowindow when pressed.

My problem is that when I create a new marker all the previous markers get the same info window, now I see why it is doing this, just not sure how to fix it! I can tell that the markerReg is being set to all the markers. The function region() is called first, Heres the code:

```
function region()
{
bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
listener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', addPoint);
path.clear();
while (markers.length) {
    markers.pop().setMap(null);
}

if (poly)
{
    poly.setMap(null);
}
var colour = document.getElementById("regionColour");
var pickedColour = colour.options[colour.selectedIndex].value;

poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
    strokeWeight: 3,
    strokeOpacity: 0.7,
    fillOpacity: 0.9,
    fillColor: pickedColour
});
poly.setMap(map);
poly.setPaths(new google.maps.MVCArray([path]));
markerCenter.setMap(null);
}

function stopPath()
{
    google.maps.event.clearListeners(map, 'click');
}

function clearPath()
{
bounds = null;
google.maps.event.clearListeners(map, 'click');
path.clear();
poly.setMap(null);
while (markers.length) {
    markers.pop().setMap(null);
}
markerCenter.setMap(null);
}

function addPoint(event) {
path.insertAt(path.length, event.latLng);

markerReg = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: event.latLng,
    map: map
});

google.maps.event.addListener(markerReg, 'rightclick', function () {
    var detailDiv = document.createElement('div');
    detailDiv.style.width = '200px';
    detailDiv.style.height = '200px';
    document.getElementById('googleMap').appendChild(detailDiv);

    var overviewOpts = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: markerReg.getPosition(),
        mapTypeId: map.getMapTypeId(),
        disableDefaultUI: true
    };

    var detailMap = new google.maps.Map(detailDiv, overviewOpts);

    if (!infoWindowMini)
        infoWindowMini = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    infoWindowMini.setContent(detailDiv);
    infoWindowMini.open(map, markerReg);
});

markers.push(markerReg);
markerReg.setTitle("#" + path.length);

centerMarker();    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, if it helps anyone. I was making a very simple mistake by declaring the markerReg variable globally. Simply changed it from `markerReg = new` to `var markerReg = new` and removed the global declaration.